# Delete Document DB successful but no response resource

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I am able to successfully delete the document from the collection, but the response object is null. 
What's missing here?

What details about the operation are supposed to be in the `ResourceResponse` object that is supposed to be returned?

```
var uri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(dbName, colName, id);
var resp = await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(uri);
response.Message = resp.Resource.ToString(); // *** Always fails here ***
if (IsSuccessStatusCode(resp.StatusCode)) { //Do something here}
```

The code always fails at the 3rd line here because `resp.Resource` is null

I have no problem getting a valid `ResourceResponse` object from `ReadDocumentAsync`, `CreateDocumentAsync`, `ReplaceDocumentAsync`

If I go to the Azure Data Explorer, I can see the document before `DeleteDocumentAsync` is executed and then the document disappears after `DeleteDocumentAsync` is executed (presumably because it has been deleted). If `DeleteDocumentAsync` is not executed, the files do not disappear.

Comment: ["The service returns an empty response body."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/delete-a-document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document is deleted so there is no `Resource` in the response because the resource doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: How would I know if this operation succeeded or failed?

Comment: The StatusCode when the Remove operation is successful is NoContent which is 204. Anything in the 2xx is considered success in HTTP. If something goes wrong then you won't get a 204 but either a 4xx or 5xx

Comment: @erad For whatever it's worth I also think you should take a look at [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut). It will probably make this way easier for you.